# Python3.6 is installed but pip3 command not found on Mac os x

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I have installed *python3.6*  and  Jupiter Notebooks on my computer using anaconda. Now, I need to install TensorFlow for python3. To show the version of pip: I type these command:

```
pip -V: pip 9.0.1 from /Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6).
pip3 -V: command not found.
```

What I understand is pip pointed to python3.6 and I can use it to install Tensorfolw (it is like a alias to pip3). Is it correct?

Comment: Does `pip3 --version` work? Does `pip3 seach tensorflow` show anything?

Comment: @9000 Yes. It gives  the same thing as pip -V

Comment: @9000, now pip3 -V, pip -V give pip 9.0.1 from /Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6).